# Problems with reading from CSV in while condition in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, csv-file

With different users I need to log to the same page and with every user I need to send same requests which contain some numbers that I have stored in CSV file (001, 002, 003) in every column one number
for exmp. I got 3 users in name.surname.a1, name surname.a2, name.surname.a3
Each if them after log in should send requests with id's that came from CSV. Each user sends reqests with same id's
So i have:

- Counter (from 1 to 3) for 3 users
- Thread group (3 users, loop 1)
- Login Sampler
- While controller (condition ${ID})// ID is the CSV variable

  - CSV Data set config (ID variable, Recycle on EOF:true, Stop thread on EOF: true, Sharin mode: All threads)

    - HTTP request with ${ID}

So with this I want for exmp
    user 1 to send the numbers 0001 0002 and 0003
than

user 2 to send the number 0001 0002 and 003

I have problem because either user 1 sends only the first number, user 2 only the second one or even though I have stop on EOF true the loop goes infintly

Comment: Is this a Development question or an SQA question?

Comment: sorry I forgot to mentioned that this is in JMeter so it's SQA. Edited.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to try a simpler way - 3 users with 3 loops in a thread group. So each user will send all 3 values from CSV file.

Your test will look like:

- Thread group (3 users, 3 loops)

  - HTTP Request

    - [CSV Data Set Config](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/65138-using-csv-data-set-config)

Answer (score 1):

Try to insert one While Controller into another:

```
-CSV Data Set Config
-While Loop controller   <-this iterates through users
--CSV Data Set Config
--While Loop Controller  <- this iterates through values for single user
```